# sql returning product of rows instead of rows actually in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql that I execute in SQL Server. I get a product of rows in the `tx` table. `tx` table has 6 rows in it and `appt` table has no matching row. `master` table has one row with personal info, but when I execute this sql I get 36 rows instead of getting one row for each record. I get the row times number of rows for this guy. I know I need another condition in the `where` clause but nothing I have tried works:

```
SELECT "tx"."today",
       "tx"."ada_no",
       "tx"."tth_no",
       "tx"."surface",
       "tx"."billed",
       "tx"."ins_pays",
       "tx"."ins_pays1",
       "tx"."balance1",
       "tx"."dr_no",
       "tx"."status",
       "tx"."coma",
       "tx"."comb",
       "tx"."notes",
       "tx"."appt",
       "tx"."w_date",
       "tx"."thekey",
       "tx"."service",
       "tx"."time",
       "appt"."doa",
       "master"."wip",
       LEFT(ampm, 1) AS premed,
       "master"."med_hx",
       "tx"."comc",
       "tx"."comd",
       "tx"."i_bal2",
       "tx"."ins_pays2",
       "tx"."i_bal3",
       "tx"."ins_pays3"
FROM   "tx"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "appt"
         ON "tx"."appt_key" = "appt"."appt_key",
       "master"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "tx" tx1
         ON "master"."master_key" = "tx1"."master_key"
WHERE  "master"."master_key" = CAST(71563.00 AS NUMERIC(10, 2))
       AND "master"."master_key" = "tx"."master_key"
ORDER  BY "tx"."time" ASC,
          "tx"."appt" ASC
```

Comment: What's with all the double quotes?

Comment: Why are you using both commas and `JOIN` operators in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: How do you read that query? It's giving me seizures. I think it's ironic there is a column called `coma` in there.

Comment: OK: here is the query without the quotes:

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your data, but I'm guessing that you are seeing these results because `tx` is left joining on itself.

I am having a hard time understanding what exactly you need, but if include your current data and your desired output we could probably point you in the right direction.

On a side note, I don't see any reason for you to have all those double quotes in there.  If you remove those and format your query it will be much easier for people here to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the vagaries of typing an answer too quickly. The original query was generating too many records due to the structure of the join, which used a *left outer* construct. Obviously a cross join creates the cross product of each involved table.

Comment: You explained cross join.Left join means all the rows from left table and matching rows from right table.If no matching rows in right table then those rows will have null as values for right table columns.

Comment: I am new to ansi sql and am used to using old sql but here is what actually needed to be done, that fixed the problem:

Comment: sorry pressed enter too quickFROM tx LEFT OUTER JOIN appt ON tx.appt_key = appt.appt_key 
 INNER JOIN master ON master.master_key = tx.master_key     
WHERE  master.master_key = CAST(71563.00 AS NUMERIC(10,2)) 
AND master.master_key = tx.master_key
ORDER BY tx.time          ASC,           tx.appt          ASC

Comment: i don't know how to format the comment but basically discussing it here in this forum did help, i removed the comma and did an inner join between tx and master since there was left outer join already on tx and appt, there was no need to have another instance of tx and alias it tx1, i hope i m mking sense

Comment: Good.Then it should have worked.Even I am new and in comments part if you press enter it basically is posted.I have same issues.Slowly you will get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FROM "tx" LEFT OUTER JOIN "appt" ON "tx"."appt_key" = "appt"."appt_key" inner join
"master" 
on "master"."master_key" = CAST(71563.00 AS NUMERIC(10,2))  
AND "master"."master_key" = "tx"."master_key" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tx" tx1 ON "master"."master_key" = "tx1"."master_key"      

ORDER BY "tx"."time"          ASC,           "tx"."appt"          ASC
```

Comment: I making all the changes suggested but still getting 36 rows

Comment: What you are doing here is that first joining the tx with master thus you have 6 rows after that join on master_key and I am sure that all 6 rows has same master key.Then the output of this is being joined with tx table and this is same table and thus have the same master key.Thus the output of tx left join master gives 6 rows with same master key value say 1 and then again it is joined with tx again and it has 6 rows and each row has master key as 1 and  thus you have 6*6 = 36 rows as each row of th etx left join master is matching with tx1.

Comment: Best way to fix these kind of issues is to comment all the joins and then start uncommenting one by one and I am sure you will be able to find the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix old style and new style JOINs. In fact, you should avoid old style joins using commas entirely. It's not ANSI standard and can lead to confusing code. According to SQL "master" is being included as a CROSS JOIN to "tx" because you have nothing that relates it to the tx table. The cross join will cause the number of rows returned to be the multiplication product of the two pieces as each repeat for every record. Effectively your current query is this:

```
SELECT     tx.today, tx.ada_no, tx.tth_no, tx.surface, tx.billed, tx.ins_pays, tx.ins_pays1, tx.balance1, tx.dr_no, tx.status, tx.coma, tx.comb, tx.notes, tx.appt, 
                      tx.w_date, tx.thekey, tx.service, tx.time, appt.doa, master.wip, LEFT(ampm, 1) AS premed, master.med_hx, tx.comc, tx.comd, tx.i_bal2, tx.ins_pays2, 
                      tx.i_bal3, tx.ins_pays3
FROM         tx LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      appt ON tx.appt_key = appt.appt_key CROSS JOIN
                      master LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tx AS tx1 ON master.master_key = tx1.master_key
WHERE     (master.master_key = 71563.00) AND (master.master_key = tx.master_key)
ORDER BY tx.time, tx.appt
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your issue is that you are missing JOIN types - you are using JOIN syntax and you are also joining the tables with a comma.  You syntax should be like the following:

```
FROM tx 
LEFT OUTER JOIN appt 
  ON tx.appt_key = appt.appt_key
LEFT JOIN master 
   ON master.master_key = tx.master_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN tx tx1
  ON master.master_key = tx1.master_key
```

So your full query would be:

```
SELECT  tx.today
  , tx.ada_no 
  , tx.tth_no 
  , tx.surface
  , tx.billed 
  , tx.ins_pays 
  , tx.ins_pays1 
  , tx.balance1 
  , tx.dr_no
  , tx.status 
  , tx.coma
  , tx.comb 
  , tx.notes 
  , tx.appt 
  , tx.w_date 
  , tx.thekey 
  , tx.service 
  , tx.time
  , appt.doa 
  , master.wip
  , left(ampm,1) as premed
  , master.med_hx
  , tx.comc
  , tx.comd 
  , tx.i_bal2
  , tx.ins_pays2
  , tx.i_bal3
  , tx.ins_pays3
FROM tx 
LEFT OUTER JOIN appt 
  ON tx.appt_key = appt.appt_key
LEFT JOIN master 
   ON master.master_key = tx.master_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN tx tx1
  ON master.master_key = tx1.master_key
WHERE master.master_key = CAST(71563.00 AS NUMERIC(10,2)) 
ORDER BY tx.time ASC
  , tx.appt ASC
```

Comment: no matter what i try i get 36 rows which i know is not correct because when i only select from tx table for this guy i only get 6 rows, master has only 1 row and appt no rows somehow tx and tx1 are joining and i m getting the product

Answer (score 0):

The comma just before the word master looks out of place to me.

```
FROM   "tx"        
LEFT OUTER JOIN "appt"          
  ON "tx"."appt_key" = "appt"."appt_key",   -- try without this comma     
"master"        
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tx" tx1          
  ON "master"."master_key" = "tx1"."master_key"
```